# Open a Python script from another Python script in another shell

Tags: python, call, raspbian

I am working currently on Raspbian. My Problem is i have a Python scrip with a infinite Loop that never should stop. In This script i want to call another script without the main script stopping. I tried different methodes to do this like:

```
import test1
test1.some_func()
```

or

```
execfile("test1.py")
```

or

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("python test1.py")
```

I could start the test1.py script with these solutions, but the script that called it would stop working. So my question is how to start a second script without the first one to stop.

Comment: Did you try to start it in a separate thread? Or I think subprocess should have a flag for that purpose, check the doc

Comment: Can you include the infinite loop and `test1.some_func()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess.call` waits for the command to complete and thus blocks your loop. You should use something like `process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "test1.py"])`. If you want to wait for the process to terminate, you can then call `process.wait()`.

Comment: that was it it works with 

subprocess.Popen 

thank you very much